# Is there any connection other than just happening at the same time between the event before 'as' and the event after 'as' in this sentence?

Tags: conjunctions, as

I have already read through many answers about "as" here on ELL.
But I am not sure about the below.

I guess "as" in the below sentence implies that there is relationship of happening at the same time between the two things. What bothers me is if there is also any subtle, hidden relationships other than that.

> Samsung snaps up AI startup Viv as Note 7 smokes out a Southwest Air flight.

To speak clearly, I wonder whether there is any connection other than the time relationship of the two happening at the same time between the event written before "as" and the event written after "as".

Thank you, very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your sentence

> Samsung snaps up AI startup Viv **as** Note 7 smokes out a Southwest Air flight.

**As** is used to not only show that two events are happening at the same time, but to also contrast two different things: *something* good with *something* bad.

Obviously, the Samsung's problems with Note 7 were disastrous for the company.  Meanwhile, the acquisition of Viv as a better form of Siri is a positive.

Another example of using **as** would be

> Titanic sank in the icy north Atlantic **as** the band played on.

Answer (score 1):

I think the conjunction "as"  is used with reference to time, to underline that the two events are happening during the same period of time. The fact that "as" means also "because", though not in this case, might suggest that one event (the former) is probably a consequence of the  other (the latter).

***[As](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/as)*** as a conjunction:

> The conjunction as has several different meanings. We use as when one event happens while another is in progress (‘during the time that’). In this case the verb after is often in the continuous form.
>
> - I saw him as I was coming into the building.

Cambridge Dictionary

Comment: Thank you for the kind explanation. Your explanation was very helpful. I appreciate it. :)